# Elapsed time between

Tags: php, datetime

I’m being sent two datetime strings.

```
$StartDateTime = '2012-12-25T23:00:43.29';
$EndDateTime = '2012-12-26T06:50:43.29';
```

I need to perform a timediff to yield elapsed time as well as assign the date component to one column and time component to another column.  What I am doing is this:

```
$d1 = new DateTime();
$d2 = new DateTime();

list($year,$month,$day) = explode('-',mb_strstr($StartDateTime,'T', TRUE));
list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':',trim(mb_strstr($StartDateTime,'T', FALSE),'T'));
$d1->setDate($year,$month,$day);
$d1->setTime($hour,$minute,$second);
list($year,$month,$day) = explode('-',mb_strstr($EndDateTime,'T', TRUE));
list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':',trim(mb_strstr($EndDateTime,'T', FALSE),'T'));
$d2->setDate($year,$month,$day);
$d2->setTime($hour,$minute,$second);

$diff = $d1->diff($d2);
```

Now, I can get $diff in whatever formats I want with:

```
$thisformat = $diff->format('%H:%I:%S');
$thatformat = $diff->format('%H%I%S');
```

And, I could get the separate DATE and TIME components into their respective object properties (both string) with:

```
$somedateproperty = $d1->format('Y-m-d');
$sometimeproperty = $d1->format('H:i:s');
$anotherdateproperty = $d2->format('Y-m-d');
$anothertimeproperty = $d2->format('H:i:s');
```

Keep thinking there should be something easier to convert those strings rather than all that parsing every time.  And, that is my question.  How could I do this more easily?

Comment: Take a look at `createFromFormat`: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) as suggested by [jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169432/elapsed-time-between/16003469#comment21365174_15169432) makes it very simple:-

```
$StartDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u", '2012-12-25T23:00:43.29');
$EndDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u", '2012-12-26T06:50:43.29');

var_dump($StartDateTime->diff($EndDateTime));
```

Gives the following output:-

```
object(DateInterval)[3]
  public 'y' => int 0
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 0
  public 'h' => int 7
  public 'i' => int 50
  public 's' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**You do not need any datetime parsing**, because your input format is standard SOAP format.

You can just do:

```
$d1 = new DateTime('2012-12-25T23:00:43.29');
```

[See more on supported formats.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)